# Give bottom constraint to the view in uitableviewcell which has more height

Tags: swift, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I have the following UITableViewCell, which contains label and imageview. Height of the image view is constant but the height of the label changes according to the text.

How can I give the bottom constraint, so that is label height is small, then height of the cell should be according to imageviewsize and if lable size is more it should be according to label
I want the cell to look like the way its in the image[image]

Comment: Try to add constraints to 4 side (trailing, leading, top and bottom) you should not give fixed height constraint neither your label nor your image view.

Comment: But Imageview is of fixed height for all the cell

Comment: If you use fixed height it probably can't change cell size.

Comment: @user2185354 does your problem still exists?

Answer (score 1):

First give your **TableView rowHeight** to **UITableViewAutomaticDimension**. It will allow tableView cell Height to grow according to his contents:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

**or**

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

As it easy to give name first so you have in your tableViewCell:- ImageView, messageLabel, profileNameLabel and timeLabel.

**Step1:**
Give your **ImageView** constraint **Top** and **Left** to superView(**Content View**) and timeLabel to Right to superView also Align **Center Y** to your **ImageView**.

**Step2:**
Now in the middle give your **messageLable** constraint Top to **superView**, Left to **imageView** and Right to **superView**.
**Make sure messageLable no of line is 0.**

**Step3:**
Then give your **profileNameLable**  constraint Top and Leading to **messageLable**.

**Step4:**
So now to make your tableViewCell Height will grow according to your contents(messageLable variable height). Give your profileNameLabel **bottom Grater than equal to**(**>=**) constraints to SuperView(**ContentView**) e.g 20

[image]

also **ImageView** bottom **Grater than equal to(>=)** constraints to SuperView(**ContentView**) e.g 20. So when the messageLabel will have more height **it will push cell Height** and when it has normal height then cell will take height from your ImageView.

**Grater then equal to (>=)** Constraint (it's basically means always maintain that **margin** of e.g 20 pixels space so it can go more then 20 pixels but not less then that)

[image]